# Sending curl requests in Groovy script

Tags: json, curl, jenkins, groovy

I am having difficulty sending a curl request within a Groovy script.

I keep getting invalid payload and globbing errors. If I do the following within my terminal it works fine

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"attachments": [{"color": "#2A9B3A", "author_name": "Richard Lewis", "title": "MY Build Status", "title_link": "http://example.co.uk", "text": "Successful Build" }]}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/webhook
```

But when I try and do this within my Groovy script it fails

```
sh """#!/bin/bash -l
      curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data {"attachments": [{"color": "#2A9B3A", "author_name": "Richard Lewis", "title": "My Build Status", "title_link": "http://example.co.uk", "text": "Successful Build" }]} "https://hooks.slack.com/services/T122JHEUW/webhook"
   """
```

How would I format this correctly or is there a better way to send this request? It would be cleaner if i could save the `--data` in a variable to pass into my request I know but I had problems with that also (payload errors), I guess down to formatting again.

Comment: Alternative simplest way to do - https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite

Comment: i just come across that... Thanks, trying as we speak :-)

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any wrapping around your json (using quotes) after `--data`. May be that is a reason. You can try using single quote around your json (similar to your other curl command, i.e. `--data '{...}'`)

There is an option using json into a file and then use `--data-binary` to post from a file. For example the below one.

```
--data-binary "@my.json"
```

And, finally, of course you may use any groovy client (or library) that do similar things like curl. I don't know much about groovy.